# Getting a Boolean value JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

I have a group of nodes within a `GridPane` and have some listeners adding and removing those nodes from the `GridPane`.

I was wondering if there is a way for me to create a get method(Boolean) or such to test if the nodes are currently in the `GridPane` or not.

I want to enable the button when the nodes aren't in the gridpane aka `false`.

Any help/thoughts appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post the code that isn't working so that others can evaluate how best to fix your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how you can check for the presence of a node:

```
gridpane.getChildren().contains(yourNode);
```

Comment: Thank you! This has solved my problem, it's hard sometimes finding the correct parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if [the parent of the `Node node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#parentProperty) that you want to check is the `GridPane`. This should be a bit faster than using the child list, since it does not require iterating through the child list:

```
node.getParent() == gridPane
```

You can also use bindings to enable/disable the button (assuming there is a single node that decides, if the `Button` should be enabled or disabled)

```
button.disableProperty().bind(node.parentProperty().isEqualTo(gridPane));
```